# How to get length of a string in Octave?

Tags: octave

How do I get the length of a string in Octave?

I looked [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-Strings.html#Manipulating-Strings) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Comparing-Strings.html#Comparing-Strings) and [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/String-Conversions.html#String-Conversions) for some equivalent to PHP's strlen(), but I did not find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the first link you posted explains, strings are just matrices, so you can use the regular matrix operations, for instance [length](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Object-Sizes.html#doc-length).

```
> x = "teststring";
> length(x)
ans = 10
```

Comment: In MATLAB this gives `ans=1`. Why would Octave decide to implement this differently from MATLAB?

Comment: It seems MATLAB didn't introduce string arrays until 2016b. Interesting.

Comment: before Matlab 2016b chars only used single quote. double was simply not used, while Octave allowed either for character arrays (some minor differences in handling special characters). now Matlab uses " to create string objects. Octave is working on a string class, but it'll break some things. for now double quotes still create char arrays. so, "teststring" and 'teststring" are still length=10 in Octave. in Matlab 'teststring' has length=10, but "teststring" is 1 string so length=1. The question is why Matlab decided this and when will Octave will break backward compatibility to follow suit.